# C# ASP.NET project with Facebook login - not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, oauth, authorization

I want to create a ASP.NET project (Single Page Application) and activate Facebook login. But now 2 days later I can not get it work!

I have:
Visual Studio 2015

This is my steps:

1. Create a new ASP.NET 4.6 (Single Page Application) -project.
2. Uncomment this and added appid and appsecret (fake here):

   ```
   app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
       appId: "5675675657567567",
       appSecret: "346n3636n34n6346n346n346n346n346");
   ```
3. Created a new Facebook app with this settings:

> ```
> -Client OAuth Login: on
>
> -Web OAuth Login: on
>
> -App Domains: localhost
>
> -Valid OAuth redirect URIs: http://localhost:63496/signin-facebook
> ```
>
> And added the real appid and secret.

When I click on the facebook login button, i can login to facebook but i just redirect back to my homepage and nothing happens, I am not logged in at all. Next time I click on the facebook login button it seems that i am already logged in on facebook so I just redirect back again directly.

So the question is, how can I login to my homepage via Facebook? Can I not login correctly in debug-mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply update the package `Windows.Owin.Security.Facebook` to the latest version (3.1.0)

Further, in the Facebook application update the "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" to "http://localhost:xxxx/signin-facebook" (where **xxxx** represents the port number) every thing works...

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I tried setting up OATH2 with Facebook for login to my MVC5 app. Got the appId AppSecret and plugged them in. Ensured SSL was enabled. But Facebook does not seem to authorize and I get into the same loop you mention.

I then proceeded to set up the same with Google, and it worked just fine. The problem seems to be with the Facebook API (.. or something :) )

Comment: Hmmm, I updated the OWIN for Google, Facebook and Microsoft in the nuget management, so now Microsoft and Facebook works. Not Google...

Answer (score 0):

1) Need to install "facebook" nuget package in c# project.

2) Must to create facebook app from https://developers.facebook.com/ and  store **appId** and **appSecret** in your application.

3) Execute below code for facebook authorization and call "FacebookLogin" method on action event.

```
   [HttpPost]
    public string FacebookLogin()
    {
        try
        {
            // Instantiate the Facebook client
            var oauth = new FacebookClient();                
            var fbLoginUrl = oauth.GetLoginUrl(new
            {
                client_id = "Enter ApplicationID",
                client_secret = "Enter ApplicationSecret",
                redirect_uri = "Enter RedirectUri",
                response_type = "code",
                scope = "manage_pages,email" // Add other permissions as needed
            });
            var fbloginUri = fbLoginUrl.AbsoluteUri;
            Session["ClientId"] = "Enter ApplicationID",                
            return fbloginUri;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }            
    }
```